# Unable to set pdfkeywords

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks, keywords, hyperxmp

When I use the `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}` packages, I am unable to set the pdfkeywords text as intended; instead, some unwanted content is present. Like below screen shot.

Before using those packages

[image]

After using these packages (unwanted text like **semi-colon**, **double quotes** and **en-US**)

[image]

MWE is below,

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}


\hypersetup{
   pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
   pdftitle={O Hai},
   pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.,
   pdfkeywords={keyword1, keyword2}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\DocumentMetadata` as I told you in your previous question?

Comment: Also, why phase II - it's been superceded

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer and Joseph Wright,
 I need to use PDF accessibility, so I am using those packages.

Comment: `\DocumentMetadata` does the same, it is the new version of the commands. Believe me, I wrote that code, I know what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Keywords can be stored in two places in a PDF: in the Info dictionary and in the XMP-metadata. In the Info dictionary the keywords are encoded as simple string, in the XMP metadata they are encoded as xml-list and can contain language attributes.

The PDF/A and PDF/UA-standards contain various requirements about the Info dictionary: in A-4 and PDF/UA-2 the Info dictionary should not be used at all. In earlier standards it can be used but the values of entries should be "the same" as the one in the XMP metadata -- something that is difficult to implement as they have different formats.

How PDF viewer should present the keywords to the user is not specified. Some viewer only use the Info dictionary and show nothing if it is not there, some viewer prefer the XMP-data. If the XMP-data is used the keywords are sometimes separated by semicolons, sometimes quotes are used (e.g. if the keyword contains a comma) and the language data is sometimes shown and sometimes not.

If I update your document to the current syntax (see below) and compile with a current PDF management then the XMP-metadata contains

```
   <dc:subject>
    <rdf:Bag>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">keyword1</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">keyword2</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
   </dc:subject>
```

and the Info dictionary contains `keyword1,keyword2`.

Acrobat makes out of this

[image]

PDFix shows

[image]

Foxit shows

[image]

So there is nothing that can be done to make them "nice looking" in all cases on the LaTeX side. Complain to the PDF viewer if you don't like it how they show the keywords.

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
   pdftitle={O Hai},
   pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.,
   pdfkeywords={keyword1,keyword2}
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```